# Write like this "{{ My Code hear }}" in laravel view

Tags: laravel

My code

`$data = "{{ hello World }}";`

then

`<p>{{ $data }}</p>`

that's show a blank page.

I need this result like this

`{{ Hello World }}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$data = "{{". hello World ."}}";`

then
`{{ $data }}`and 
It will provide this result in your view. 
{{ hello World }}